# Получение знака «Голос народа» не отображается в достижениях

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки

**Ситуация:**

Знак «голос народа» не отобразился даже спустя полчаса после получения в «достижениях». Знак же за метку там отобразился. См. скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

Баг это, фича или надо подождать?

**UPD_0:**

Ещё плюсов покидал - «Глас народа» получил и в достижениях сразу увидел, а «голос народа» так и не появляется. Определённо баг.

**UPD_1:**

Два с лишним дня прошло, а знака в "достижениях" всё нет(

Comment: Мне только что «Наставник» присвоился с опозданием на день. Возможно, заржавевший кеш можно сдвинуть, тыкнув на шестеренку в своем профиле, а потом по нужному знаку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в шестерёнке знак отмечен галочкой как полученный уже и не кликабелен. В "достижениях" его так и нет, хотя с момента его получения я уже 3 других знака успешно получил(

Comment: Что в итоге, присвоился знак?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, знак присвоился, но в панельке верхней сайта так и не появился... Вроде бы и баг, но совсем не страшный. Будь я разработчиком SO я бы, пожалуй, забил на это)))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ух ты, у вас уже ромб показывается)

Comment: ага, с утра уже. И кнопочки синие доступны ) И метки багтрекинга расставляю вот по Мете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ждём от вас многа букаф на тему "новая эра ru-SO"! =)))

Comment: да какая новая — та же самая эра. Просто модераторы удвоились, было 2, стало 4.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, бюрократический аппарат разрастается)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во всех случаях, когда

- какой-то знак не присвоился или не отображается в ленте,
- рейтинг за метки не насчитался,

подождите в течение суток, или хотя бы до серверной полночи. Многие показатели пересчитываются не моментально, а раз в сутки, чтобы не перегружать сервер. Серверное время можно узнать в верхнем правом углу ленты достижений.

С присвоением знаков задержки бывают и до двух суток, но знак всегда присваивается.

Comment: Ну, как в UPD я писал следующий знак моментально появился. Сейчас уже новые серверные сутки, а непоявившийся - так и не появился. Подожду ещё денёк(

Comment: Всё ещё нет знака. Точно баг.

Comment: Знак появляется в достижениях, но в оповещениях нет. Тоже считаю багом

Comment: @EugenKonkov всё ещё не появился?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: нет знак в оповещениях, не появился.